# Which type of oscillator should I use?

Tags: oscillator

I want to make induction heater. So I want to make oscillator for this. I want to make oscillator with transistor, inductor, resistor, diode and capacitors but not IC, relay switch, op amps etc. Which oscillator should I make?

The required frequency of oscillator is from 15-50 kHz.

Comment: So you want a 10,000 watt oscillator?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  i want to make oscillator for induction heater to melt aluminum cans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of options, but here are a couple of examples:

---

The first (which is really a pulse generator), from [Unijunction Transistor](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/unijunction-transistor.html), shows that there are three outputs that can be taken: V<sub>C1</sub> (sawtooth), V<sub>B1</sub> (positive pulse) and V<sub>B2</sub> (negative pulse):

[image: Unijunction Transistor oscillator]

$$T = \frac{1}{f}= R_3Cln\left(\frac{1}{1-\eta}\right)$$

For a 2N2646 Unijunction Transistor, the intrinsic stand-off ratio η as 0.65, as stated in the data sheet.

---

An example of an astable multivibrator using emitter-coupled oscillators can be found in [Electronics Tutorials - Astable Multivibrator](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html)

[image: Emitter-coupled oscillator]

The periodic time is given by:

$$T = t_1 + t_2$$

$$t_1 = 0.69R_3C_1$$
$$t_2 = 0.69R_2C_2$$

If

$$R_2 = R_3$$

and

$$C_1 = C_2$$

then the frequency of the resultant symmetric waveform is given by:

$$f= \frac{1}{T} = \frac{1}{1.38RC}$$

---

I, myself, looked into the subject of oscillators recently, and I found some which used only discrete components and came up with a number of options, which I listed in my blog, [Swingers](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2018/04/29/swingers/).

Comment: Can multivibrator provide the 15-50 khz frequency?

Comment: Yes, if you chose appropriate values for C1 and R2. I'll update my answer with some equations shortly

Comment: thank you for your answer